# How to get integer values from json array

Tags: android, json

Response of my `json` is given below,and I am trying to `parse data`,but when I parse `user_photo_id`,it gives `JSONException:No values for user_photo_id`,can any one tell me?

```
{  
  "user_login_id": "2650",  
  "user_total_photo": "3",  
  "max_upload_photo": "3",  
  "image_list": [  
    {  
      "user_photo_id": 334,  
      "status": "Approved",  
      "photo": ""  
    },  
    {  
      "user_photo_id": 394,  
      "status": "Approved",  
      "photo": ""  
    },  
    {  
      "user_photo_id": 398,  
      "status": "Admin Approve Remaining",  
      "photo": ""  
    }  
  ]  
}
```

my java code:

```
 class LoadImages extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>> {


         String photoid;
        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... args) {
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(IMAGE_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);


                try {
                    jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);


                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(IMAGE_USERLOGIN_ID, jsonObj.getString(IMAGE_USERLOGIN_ID));
                        map.put(IMAGE_TOTAL_PHOTO,jsonObj.getString(IMAGE_TOTAL_PHOTO));
                        map.put(IMAGE_MAX_UPLOAD, jsonObj.getString(IMAGE_MAX_UPLOAD));
                        /*map.put(IMAGE_USER_PHOTOID, jsonObj.getString(IMAGE_USER_PHOTOID));
                        map.put(IMAGE_STATUS, jsonObj.getString(IMAGE_STATUS));
                        map.put(IMAGE_PHOTO, jsonObj.getString(IMAGE_PHOTO));
                        */




                        image_list = (JSONArray) jsonObj.get(IMAGE_LISTING);
                        for(int i=0;i< image_list.length();i++)
                        {
                           photoid += image_list.get(i);
                           Log.d("mylog", "initial marital  = " + photoid);

                        }

                          getActivity().runOnUiThread(new  Runnable() 
                     {
                        @Override
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),PhotoView.class);
                            intent.putExtra("id", id);
                            intent.putExtra("totals", totalphota);
                            intent.putExtra("maxs", maximumphota);

                            startActivity(intent);
                        } 
                    });
                       /* image_list = (JSONArray) jsonObj.get("user_photo_id");
                        image_list=(JSONArray) jsonObj.get(IMAGE_STATUS);
                        image_list=(JSONArray)jsonObj.get(IMAGE_PHOTO);
                        for(int i=0;i< image_list.length();i++)
                        {
                          String photoid=

                        }*/

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            return data;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);


            // dismiss the dialog after getting all albums
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            /*Intent mIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),Filter.class);
            Bundle extras = mIntent.getExtras();
            try {
                extras.putString("radiostatus", jsonObj.getString(FILTER_ALLOW));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  */


        }

    }
```

Comment: Just write jsonObj.getInt(IMAGE_USERLOGIN_ID);

Comment: i dont want user login id,i want userphotoid

Comment: just write this jsonObj.getInt("user_photo_id");

Comment: mage_list = (JSONArray) jsonObj.getInt(IMAGE_USER_PHOTOID);  i tried like this..and it  shows Cannot cast from int to JSONArray

Comment: can you show me parse code ?

Comment: its already there in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope that helps. You just need to follow the structure of your json string. ( The json array contains json objects so get the json object first in the loop, then from that get the user_photo_id )

```
image_list = (JSONArray) jsonObj.get("image_list");
for(int i=0;i< image_list.length();i++)
{
   JSONObject imageListItem = image_list.getJSONObject(i);
   int  userPhotoId = imageListItem.getInt("user_photo_id")
   Log.d("mylog", "i ="+i+" and user_photo_id =" + userPhotoId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
image_list = (JSONArray) jsonObj.get(IMAGE_LISTING);
for(int i=0;i< image_list.length();i++)
{
    photoid += image_list.get(i);//here you made a mistake
    Log.d("mylog", "initial marital  = " + photoid);

}
```

In your json , image_list is JsonArray , But each element in this array is an JsonObject, so you will get a JsonObject use `image_list.get(i)` not int. So you should do more task:

```
image_list = jsonObj.getJSONArray(IMAGE_LISTING);
for(int i=0;i< image_list.length();i++)
{
    photoid += image_list.getJSONObject(i).getInt("user_photo_id");
    Log.d("mylog", "initial marital  = " + photoid);

}
```

**Update to send json data to other Activities:**

1.Create a class to store your data like this :

```
public class JsonData{
    private JsonObject mData;

    //getter and setter and other function you need
}
```

2.implements Serializable:

```
public class JsonData implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6037391814333931008L;//It should generate by your IDE
    private JsonObject mData;

    //getter and setter and other function you need
}
```

3.Use Bundle and Intent to sent Serializable data when start Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Sender.this, Receiver.class); // replace Sender and Receiver with your Activities 
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("Your Key", yourDataClass);//replace yourDataClass with your JsonData class
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

4.Receive data in other Activity:

Add code in onCreate of this Activity:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (bundle != null) {

        Serializable data = bundle.getSerializable("Your Key");

        if (data != null) {
            JsonData jsonData= (JsonData) data;
            //now you have got your data and do whatever you want.
        }
    }
```

But, the code in Step 4 should also be placed in onNewIntent if the Activity is `singleTask` mode. In this condition , you should save Intent in `onNewIntent`:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
    //here to place the code in Step 4 and also place in onCreate function
}
```

Comment: what if i need to send all objects which is inside array to next activity?

Comment: You should create a class which contains the data you want to send, and let this class implements `Serializable`.And there is code to send:Intent intent = new Intent(..., ...);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("key", yourDataClass);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);`I think here shouldn't write lots of code`

Comment: @androidlover sure,wait a moment

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652852/how-to-send-id-to-server-using-json